# how to create special layout folder for galaxy note only?

Tags: android, android-layout, naming-conventions

Currently, i had 6 set of layouts folder which were small, normal, large, xlarge, sw600dp and default. I had 5 sets of drawable which were default, ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi.

The galaxy note 4.0.3 run the large with hdpi. However the screen resolution for galaxy note is the largest among all the large screen category. The output is difference with those S2, S3 and so on.

How to naming the folder for specific only galaxy note such as sw600dp for tab only?

Answer (score 0):

Look the comments that specify the folder name like you want (`layout-large-port-xhdpi-1280x800`)
[Click Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9826803/android-large-layout-affects-galaxy-note)